# Pub/Sub messages from snapshot not sent to Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a pub/sub topic receiving messages. This topic has a subscriber which is a Dataflow pipeline, and in case the message cannot be ack there is a snapshot that stores it. A week ago we had a bug in the pipeline and we could not send some messages. When the problem was solved, we tried to resend the messages that were stored in the pub/sub snapshot. The problem is those messages were not arriving to the Dataflow pipeline although they were arriving to the topic. So my question is: why does this happen? I would expect any message entering that topic to be consumed by the pipeline, but it is obviously not the case

Comment: When you say "there is a snapshot that stores it," what do you mean? You mean you've used the [snapshot feature](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#seek_to_a_snapshot) to create a subscription snapshot?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn yes, we created a subscription snapshot to collect messages in case there was any problem with the pipeline in order to not lose them.

Comment: Were the messages published more than 7 days ago? The maximum retention duration for messages is 7 days.

Comment: No, the messages were published the day before.